# ES6 import statement benefits

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export

Pretty basic question about ES6 import. Why should we export modules and then import it in another JS file? What benefit do we get doing this? What are the other ways (even if it's crude) to accomplish this without doing an export and import? in other words if I were to work on ES5 how would I do this export and import?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why should we export modules and then import it in another JS file? What benefit do we get doing this?

The entire point of modules is to provide a convenient and clean and simple way for developers to organize their code into reusable or shareable modules.  So, the point of using modules is to develop your code in modular ways.

Modules can:

1. Be shared among projects easily.
2. Be tested independently.
3. Have their own namespace and scope and can have private variables.
4. Provide a clear and cleanly defined interface to a body of code.
5. Can be connected with a code loading mechanism for loading pieces of code.

While all of this could be done without a language-defined structure, then there would be lots of different ways people might do it and far fewer people would structure their code for these benefits.

These benefits can be very clearly seen for node.js development with the thousands of modules available through NPM.  Without a standard module design that everyone subscribes to, it simply isn't easy to share lots and lots of pieces of code that all do different things.  The ES6 module system is an attempt to standardize this mechanism.

> If I were to work on ES5 how would I do this export and import?

You'd have to either find a 3rd party module system to adopt (there were many in the days before ES6 such as AMD or CommonJS) or build your own or go without and probably give up on some of the above benefits.  The node.js module system is one such system designed outside of the Javascript language standard.  Because it came built into node.js and was the primary mechanism by which a node.js project loaded multiple source files, it became the de-facto standard for node.js development.

Or, you can now use transpilers like Babel that will let you write code in ES6 and they will translate it to ES5-compatible code for you.  You add a "build" step to your code that fits in the build process kind of like compiling another language (except you're doing transpiling instead of compiling) and you get the advantages of writing and debugging in ES6, but your code maintains compatibility with ES5 runtime engines (e.g. old browsers), with only a few limitations.

Here's a useful article on [Why Modules](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html) for more info on the topic?